# Octave Get line number of error

Tags: octave

The error I'm getting is not very descriptive, it will tell me

`error: gradientDescent: product: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x97, op2 is 97x2)`

I know the file is gradientDescent.m, but is there a way to get the line number of the error?

Comment: the next line typically contains the line number. Without providing more info and/or some code which shows the problem no one is able to help you. And the error message is pretty clear, isn't it?

Comment: @Andy yeah the error message is pretty clear, it took me maybe 2 minutes to find and fix it. I purposely didn't copy and paste my code because I don't need stackoverflow to debug my code, my question was getting the line number. But the problem is I've had this type of error multiple times and each time I have to track down the line. The line underneath the error message is even less descriptive, it just says error: gradientDescent. In most other languages if there's an error it'll tell you the line number so I was hoping Octave had a way to do that?

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clearer: GNU Octave SHOULD show the line where the error happens. So if you say there is no line number in the error message this might be a bug. But to reproduce this you have to provide a MCVE which triggers the error message and also mention used GNU Octave version and operating system

Answer (score 2):

`lasterror()` contains a stack trace.

In my application, I'm getting the message "error: plot: properties must appear followed by a value", with no line number.

After I get the prompt back, I can example the stack trace like this:

```
octave:23> lasterror().stack
ans =

  6x1 struct array containing the fields:

    file
    name
    line
    column
    scope
    context

octave:24> lasterror().stack.file
ans = /usr/share/octave/4.2.2/m/plot/draw/private/__plt__.m
ans = /usr/share/octave/4.2.2/m/plot/draw/plot.m
ans = /home/baccala/WAM/waveletauditory/SOM-Toolbox/som/vis_trajgui.m
ans = /home/baccala/WAM/waveletauditory/SOM-Toolbox/som/vis_trajgui.m
ans = /home/baccala/WAM/waveletauditory/SOM-Toolbox/som/vis_trajgui.m
ans = /home/baccala/WAM/waveletauditory/SOM-Toolbox/som/vis_trajgui.m
octave:25> lasterror().stack.line
ans =  96
ans =  223
ans =  616
ans =  567
ans =  548
ans =  253
octave:26>
```

Which tells me that the troublesome call to `plot` in on line 616 of `vis_trajgui.m`.